# Post facebook comment with respect to object id graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a cordova app, my requirement is to post a comment with respect to object id, as per my investigation till now it seems that we can post comment with respect to the post id, but when i post comment with respect to object id it gives me an error as  "message": "(#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin", however i can get all comments with respect to object id but cannot post one, is there any way to post comment with respect to object id ?? for example post a comment to google.com object.

Comment: No, you can not add comments to external URLs; that is only possible via the Comments plugin.

Comment: @CBroe wht is this comment plugin ???

Comment: Seriously …? https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+comments+plugin